# Commutation relation for Hamiltonian for fermion and boson

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, hamiltonian, commutator

[image: The problem]

[image: relevant information]

I feel like this is a dumb question since it isn't supposed to be this difficult. I am just confused on how the wavefunction is supposed to "interact" with the integral if you will. Since the Hamiltonian here in eq(4) is defined as the sum of two indefinite integrals, it intuitively feels like they should then commute since the integral itself can't really interact with the wavefunction if that makes sense. Obviously I am incorrect, but I can't figure out why.

For a function $f$ and $\int g(x) dx$, it doesn't make sense to me that
\begin{equation}
f\int g(x)dx - \left(\int g(x)dx\right) f \neq 0
\end{equation}

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to shed some light!

Comment: But $f$ and $g$ are not functions in this case; they are operators.  And operators don't commute.  In fact, for bosonic field operators $[\psi(\vec{r}),\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{r}')] = \delta (\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$ and for fermionic field operators, $[\psi(\vec{r}),\psi^{\dagger}(\vec{r}')]_+ = \delta (\vec{r}-\vec{r}')$, where $[\cdot,\cdot]_+$ is the anti-commutator.

Comment: @march I still don't understand how it would work with the operator under the integral. Would it be like $[\Psi, \int f dx] = \Psi\int f dx- \int f\Psi dx$? I understand they won't commute but I am at a loss on how to find what it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary thing to understand is the following:
\begin{align}
\left[\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j),\int d^3r\, \hat{g}(\vec{r})\right]
&=
\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j)\left(\int d^3r\, \hat{g}(\vec{r})\right)
-\left(\int d^3r\, \hat{g}(\vec{r})\right)\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j)
\\&=
\int d^3r\, (\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{g}(\vec{r}))
-\int d^3r\, (\hat{g}(\vec{r})\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j))
\\&=
\int d^3r\, (\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{g}(\vec{r}) - \hat{g}(\vec{r})\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j))
\\&=
\int d^3r\, [\hat{f}(\vec{r}_j),\hat{g}(\vec{r})]\,.
\end{align}
I have taken advantage of the fact that $f$ is not a function of the integration variable, and so it can be pulled into the integral on either side.

Alternatively (which is the method I use below), only work with the first term, pulling the operator in from the left, commute (or anti-commute, see below) the operator past the integrand, and then pull it out the right side, leaving the second term of the commutator that will usually cancel.

---

Here are some of the details:

First of all, the $\psi$'s are actually bosonic and fermionic field operators,  satisfying relations
\begin{align}
[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}),\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r}')]_{\pm} &= \delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}')\,,\\
[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}')]_{\pm} &= 0\,,
\end{align}
where the $[\cdot,\cdot]_-$ indicates the commutator (for bosons), and $[\cdot,\cdot]_+$ denotes the anti-commutator (for fermions).  Note that we can use the (anti-)commutator to move field operators past each other, i.e.,
\begin{align}
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})&=
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r}) \pm
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j) \mp
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\\
&=[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j),\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})]_{\pm}
\mp
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\\
&=\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_j)
\mp
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\,.
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})&=
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}) \pm
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j) \mp
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\\
&=[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j),\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})]_{\pm}
\mp
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\\
&=
\mp
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\,.
\end{align}
Then, we can do things like
\begin{align}
[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j),\hat{K}]
&=
\left[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
,-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})
\right]\\
&=\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right)
-\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right)\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\,.
\end{align}
In the first term, we can move the field operator inside the integral (because it depends on $\vec{r}_j$, not $\vec{r}$), resulting in
\begin{align}
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right)
&= 
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})
\\&=
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\left(
\delta(\vec{r}-\vec{r}_j)
\mp
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\right)\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})
\\&=
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}
\nabla_j^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\pm
\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\,,
\end{align}
where we have evaluated the first integral by integrating over the delta function, yielding functions of $\vec{r}_j$ instead of $\vec{r}$. Finally, we can move the field operator of $\vec{r}_j$ past the derivative in the second integral (because the derivative is with respect fo $\vec{r}$), and then (anti-)commute it past the last field operator, yielding
\begin{align}
\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\left(-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})\nabla^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\right)
&=
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}
\nabla_j^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)
\pm
\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\int d^3r\,
\hat{\psi}^{\dagger}(\vec{r})
\nabla^2(\mp\hat{\psi}(\vec{r})\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j))\,.
\end{align}
Since the last factor is a function of $\vec{r}_j$ and not $\vec{r}$, we can pull it out of the integral to the right. Finally, we recognize the last term as exactly the negative of the last term in the original commutator, so they cancel, leaving
\begin{align}
[\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j),\hat{K}]
=
-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}
\nabla_j^2\hat{\psi}(\vec{r}_j)\,.
\end{align}
The calculation for the interaction is similar, except that you have to commute the operator past *four* other operators, so the calculation is a little bit longer.  The mechanics are the same, though, and the same kinds of things will happen, like the cancellation of the second term in the original commutator.

Comment: Thank you so much! This cleared up a lot.